# How do I launch the default browser with a web page?

Tags: windows, browser, c++-cli, launch

I'd like to launch a web browser to visit a location in google maps from my C++/CLI .net program. What's the simplest way to launch the users current default browser?

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in Perl/Python/Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simple approach I found after some more extensive googling:

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("http://maps.google.com/");
```

Cheers for the input all.

Answer (score 1):

I got it from another post in stackoverflow

```
Process.Start( 
    new ProcessStartInfo() 
    { 
        FileName = "cmd.exe", 
        Arguments = "/c start http://www.google.com", 
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, 
        UseShellExecute = false 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

On .NET, use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx).

On VC++, VB, use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx).